# Is it bad practice to accept setState as a function parameter in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

Basically, before uploading an image to the firebase, I'm trying to control the input as:

```
export const controlThumbnail = (selectedThumbnail, setThumbnailError) => {
  if (!selectedThumbnail) {
    setThumbnailError('Please select a thumbnail!');

    return;
  }

  if (!selectedThumbnail.type.includes('image')) {
    setThumbnailError('Please select an image!');

    return;
  }

  if (selectedThumbnail.size > 1000000) {
    setThumbnailError('Image size must be less than 1MB!');

    return;
  }

  setThumbnailError(null);
};
```

which I call the above method from /lib/controlThumbnail.js to:

```
import { controlThumbnail } from '../../lib/controlThumbnail';
    
const Signup = () => {
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    thumbnail: null
  });
  const [thumbnailError, setThumbnailError] = useState(null);


  const userInputHandler = (e) => {
    setUserInfo((prevUserInfo) => {
      if (e.target.name === 'thumbnail') {
        const thumbnail = e.target.files[0];
        controlThumbnail(thumbnail, setThumbnailError);

        return { ...prevUserInfo, thumbnail };
      } else {
        return { ...prevUserInfo, [e.target.name]: e.target.value };
      }
    });
  };
...
```

so, this is now works correctly, but I wonder if this is the good way of doing it? Or should I put the control method inside the component and never give setState as parameter?

Comment: Why not just return the error message from `controlThumbnail()`, then set it to state? Why is it named 'control thumbnail', if it's only generating an error message? I don't see the need to pass it the responsibility of setting state. I'm also not sure why you aren't using `else if`s.

Comment: @Vektor oh yeah, I just did what you said and made it return only strings when one of the 'if's matches,or return null. Now I don't pass the responsibility of setting state, which was bothering me. Uh, should it be named checkThumbnail or something? I don't use else ifs there because I think the cases are (if it exists, size, and type) not relevant to each other, i mean if I also need to check type of pdf, I add else if to the second one...  is this wrong?

Comment: Theoretically speaking, `else if` could work, but it isn't necessary for this context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is subjective. Personally, I think the `controlThumbnail` function is not the right place to make that abstraction. In here, you are really only providing validation. You don't need to give it the responsibility to validate AND set some state.

You could create a pure validation function, and just use the return of this to update the state in your `Signup` component:

```js
const validateThumbnail = (thumbnail) => {
  if (!thumbnail) {
    return 'Please select a thumbnail!';
  }

  if (!thumbnail.type.includes('image')) {
    return 'Please select an image!'
  }

  if (thumbnail.size > 1000000) {
    return 'Image size must be less than 1MB!'
  }

  return null
}

const Signup = () => {
  const [userInfo, setUserInfo] = useState({
    name: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    thumbnail: null
  });
  const [thumbnailError, setThumbnailError] = useState(null);


  const userInputHandler = (e) => {
    setUserInfo((prevUserInfo) => {
      if (e.target.name === 'thumbnail') {
        const thumbnail = e.target.files[0];
        setThumbnailError(validateThumbnail(thumbnail));
        return { ...prevUserInfo, thumbnail };
      }
      return { ...prevUserInfo, [e.target.name]: e.target.value };
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I did exactly this, thank you for your post, is it okay for this validation function to live in some lib file or keep it in the component for simplicity sake?

Comment: My rule of thumb is to abstract when I need to reuse more than twice.

Comment: @imaskingbruh whichever makes most sense to you. If you want to re-use the validation elsewhere, moving it to a lib file would be good. If you only use it here, and the component is small, then leave it here. You can always move it later if it grows.